# Java - Input string into array

Tags: java, arrays, string-aggregation

I have a text file like this :

> testcaseZ : a, b, c
>
> testcaseX : b,d
>
> testcaseC : b

I want to have a string array like :

> ```
>          abcd
> ```
>
> testcaseZ     1  1  1  0
>
> testcaseX   0  1  0  1
>
> testcaseC   0  1  0  0

Comment: I don't understand the question. How are those 2 related? Do you have any code?

Comment: my progress is split some text to string.

Comment: the relation is testcase z have method a,b, and c. so the program input into array, then mark the method by 1 value if the testcase have method.

Comment: @if412001 , do you have to put testcaseX/Y/Z into this array of column one? and put the abcd into the row one?

Comment: It looks like database.

Comment: @Jaskey, I mean it's like matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class testString {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //need to configure this accordingly            
        int row=3+1;
        int col=4+1;

        String[][] array=new String[row][col];
        //construct the string with the number of row-1
        String s1="testcaseZ : a,b,c";
        String s2="testcaseX : b,d";
        String s3="testcaseC : b";
        String[] strings=new String[]{s1,s2,s3};//strings should have lenghth of row-1
        String[] allValues=new String[]{"a","b","c","d"};

        //polulate the first row
        array[0][1]="a";
        array[0][2]="b";
        array[0][3]="c";
        array[0][4]="d";
        //Above, you can  dynamically construct the two arrays based on your input(say from files)

        for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){//for every rest rows
            String text=strings[i-1];
            String theCase=text.substring(0,text.indexOf(":")).trim();//
            String valueText=text.replaceAll(theCase, "").replaceFirst(":", "").trim();         
            array[i][0]=theCase;

            String[] values=valueText.split(",");
            List valueList=Arrays.asList(values);

            for(int j=1;j<array[i].length;j++){//for every cols
                if(valueList.contains(allValues[j-1])){//if contains the value, 
                    array[i][j]="1";
                }
                else array[i][j]="0";
            }
        }

        //test the output           
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    }
}
```

output is like:

```
[[null, a, b, c, d], [testcaseZ, 1, 1, 1, 0], [testcaseX, 0, 1, 0, 1], [testcaseC, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: nice solution, how if the data from file txt which is has 500 testcase with diffrent method. like this :

test_case_001 : methodConcateWords, methodArmstrong, methodPalindrome_1, methodReverse_2

test_case_002 : methodLeapYear

test_case_003 : methodPalindrome_2

test_case_004 : methodLeapYear, methodPalindrome_1

test_case_005 : methodArmstrong, methodLeapYear, methodPalindrome_2

test_case_006 : methodArmstrong, methodLeapYear, methodPalindrome_1, methodReverse_2

test_case_007 : methodConcateWords, methodReverse_2

Comment: @if412001 It is the almost the same,unless how you get the string arrays.You can do some like: while(readline from file){construct the String array with every line}. And the rest will be the same.

Comment: may I know your email? Need ur help

Comment: @if412001 , check here to read a file into string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file . If you have further question, you can ask a question again.

Comment: could u help me about implement regression testing of heuristic method GRE